# Wordpress - keep a variable for all pages in memory from the url

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, session

I downloaded a referrer plugin and it works fine I create my custom link and everything is fine:

https://testsite.com/?r=ty5x

I have a conversion system that tells me how many users have come to my site via the custom link

if you want to see the variable associated with the custom link on the display, just do this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['r'])) {
    echo $_GET['r'];
}
?>
```

where the problem lies, that if the user changes the page and returns to the home page, obviously the url changes, how can I keep the variable r = in memory for the entire browsing session of the user

update $_SESSION

if in functions.php I write the code:

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['referrer']=$_GET['r'];

}
```

in front-page.php, write echo:

```
<?php
$username=$_SESSION['referrer'];
echo $username;
?>
```

It's perfect, but as soon as I change the page even if I activate the session_start, the variable is not seen

example second page:

```
session_start();

$test = $_SESSION['referrer'];

echo $test;
```

I also tried to enter the $ _SESSION following this example:

```
function test() {
    global $hello;
    $hello = 'hello world';
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'test' );
```

and echo:

```
global $hello;
echo $hello;
```

but no result

Comment: Yes you can use session storage. https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: Why not use sessions for this?

Comment: @NicoHaase how could i do this with wordpress, i was seeing such a thing look at my modified question

Comment: What's wrong with the given code? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: And what have you tried to make it work? According to that code sample, you only set the session value on a POST request containing a field named `wp-submit`, and you override each and every previously contained value of that session variable `referrer` with what ever is stored in the GET array, even if the value of `$_GET['r']` isn't set to anything

Comment: @NicoHaase wait sorry I pasted you the wrong code, now it appears perfectly but if I go from a page and return to home it does not appear anymore, I need it to always be memorized to insert it in the value of a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for replying late. After trying on implementing your code, I think your problem is caused this code in function.php.

```
if (!session_id()) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['referrer']=$_GET['r'];}
```

Since function.php will load on every page, when it is in the front page and there is value in `$_GET['r']`, it works perfectly. However, when you load to second page, the `$_GET['r']` has null value and it overwrites `$_SESSION['referrer']`.

The simplest solution is to check condition before initiating $_SESSION['referrer'].

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
    if($_GET['r']){
        $_SESSION['referrer']=$_GET['r'];
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not go because, check my question that I have updated

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope it will work for you